# Hadoop setup single node: PriviledgedActionException

Tags: hadoop, nosql, redhat

I do step by step to setup hadoop here http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html

i setup hadoop in redhat with root account

everything ok but when ./start-all and watch log JobTracker file look like this:

```
2013-06-11 08:31:00,194 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:31:01,195 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:31:01,196 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root cause:java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8088 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2013-06-11 08:31:01,196 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Problem connecting to HDFS Namenode... re-trying
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8088 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker$2.run(JobTracker.java:1908)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker$2.run(JobTracker.java:1906)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.initializeFilesystem(JobTracker.java:1906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.offerService(JobTracker.java:2324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.main(JobTracker.java:4792)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2100(Client.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1087)
    ... 20 more
```

Log of datanode like this:

```
2013-06-11 08:30:25,051 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Server at localhost/127.0.0.1:8088 not available yet, Zzzzz...
2013-06-11 08:30:27,052 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:30:28,053 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:30:29,054 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:30:30,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:30:31,056 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:30:32,057 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:30:33,058 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:30:34,058 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:30:35,059 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:30:36,060 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8088. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-06-11 08:30:36,061 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Server at localhost/127.0.0.1:8088 not available yet, Zzzzz...
```

my configuration xml

```
<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>fs.default.name</name>
         <value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:8088</value>
     </property>
</configuration>

<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
         <value>127.0.0.1:8089</value>
     </property>
</configuration>

<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>dfs.replication</name>
         <value>1</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

My Hots file:

```
192.168.1.211   kkapps  # Added by NetworkManager
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1        localhost
```

thanks for your investigate!

Comment: make sure NameNode is running fine.

Comment: from log it's likely namenode is not running.....

Comment: did u try ssh localhost and disabled ipv6 (as given in tutorial)? 
stop-all, format namnode and try again

Comment: ssh localhost OK Vaibhav, i'll disable ipv6 and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to services.msc Run.
Find CYGWIN sshd service. Right click on it, go to Properties and then to Log On tab.
Ensure that This account is checked with username as ./cyg_server(can vary depending on what you had entered while ssh localhost).
Now put the Password in the fields and start the sshd service. 
Now try running the code.
This should work!!!